# python print returns generator object instead of object itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Its a python silly problem and I am curious for the logic behind it.

```
num = 256

print(int(k) for k in str(num))
```

Above code returns:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000160728DDBC8>
```

If I wrap the complete thing into a list then:

```
print([int(k) for k in str(num)])
```

Now it returns:

```
[2, 5, 6]
```

Now my question is why the below code return an generator object instead of object of the "num" variable.

```
print(int(k) for k in str(num))
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `int(k) for k in str(num)` is a generator and you are asking to print it.
While `[int(k) for k in str(num)]` [`list comprehensions`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) creates a list with the generated objects and when you are asking to print it you naturally get the list with the generated objects.

If you wrote
`[print(int(k)) for k in str(num)]`  instead you would get the output:

```
2
5
6
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using an inline for loop in your print function, you create a generator object. You have to iterate through the generator object to actually get the items. When you wrap it into a list, it's called list comprehension, and the generator is iterated through into the list's items.
So, to print all the digits, you can do `print(*(int(k) for k in str(num)))` (or better: `print(*map(int, str(num)))`). Doing this will unpack the generator into seperate arguments for the print function. You can also just use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) (`print(", ".join(num))`)